# Laravel route not found but data saved in DB

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am using laravel 5 POST route in an AJAX call, I have defined it as,

```
Route::post('user/save-draft', ['as' => 'user/save-draft', 'uses' => 'UserController@saveDraft']);
```

I am also using Route::resource for the same controller above this save-draft route as,

```
Route::resource('user', 'UserController', ['except' => 'index']);
```

I am posting a form using AJAX with loading icon, what I am having strange here is that, data get save in the database, but I receive 404 error in the console like,

```
jquery.js:9664 POST http://www.example.com/user/save-draft 404 (Not Found)
```

So strange, and loading icon never get disappear which I do in ajax.done function.

While, my AJAX call is something like that,

```
var postData = {};
postData['frmSaveDraft'] = $frmSaveDraft.serialize();
startAjaxLoading()
$.ajax({
    url: "http://www.example.com/user/save-draft",
    type: "POST",
    data: postData,
    success: function (data) {
        alert('success')
        stopAjaxLoading();
    }
});
```

UPDATE: Sorry, I missed url in AJAX here in above question,

Any thoughts ?

Comment: Put the `stopAjaxLoading();` in a `complete: function() {}`-callback instead. That will make the loader stop regardless if you get an error or not (success is only triggered if the request was successful, which 404 isn't). Regarding the routing issue, I'm gonna let someone else take that.

Answer (score 0):

In controller method, I was returning response as,

```
echo json_encode(array('response' => true)); exit;
```

which was causing this issue may be exit keyword.

I have returned the response like,

```
 return Response::json(array('response' => true));
```

which works great.